# import connected and disconnected components React, Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux, enzyme

I'm new to React and Redux I'm trying to write some tests using enzyme, I was wondering if there is a way to import components as connected and disconnected components to test for both shallow rendering and full dom rendering. Here is what I mean;

`import ConnectedApp, { App } from '../App';`

is there a way to do this if not why?
Thank you

Comment: You could import like above, if you exported like `export { App }; export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);`

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri that makes sense since in one instance you are exporting App as a component only and then a connected component, and we can have as many exports in a file as we want  correct me if I am wrong

Comment: We can have only one default export but as many named export as you want

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Straight from [Redux documentation](https://redux.js.org/recipes/writing-tests#connected-components) about testing `connected` components:

> In order to be able to test the App component itself without having to
>   deal with the decorator, we recommend you to also export the
>   undecorated component:
>
> ```
> import { connect } from 'react-redux'
>  
> // Use named export for unconnected component (for tests)
> export class App extends Component { /* ... */ }
>  
> // Use default export for the connected component (for app)
> export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App)
> ```

Then you do just as you expected:

```
import ConnectedApp, { App } from '../App';
```

Comment: I really don't get why anyone doesn't write anything about testing the default export. I. M. O it is not correct to export both components. I understand that redux is tested and stuff, but with the default export you can test way more stuff instead of exporting both of them. Unit test can be tricky. You might get a passing test when you shouldn't and vice versa, just because you didn't import the default connected one... But none is talking about it...